# Generating a random number in an SHTML page

Tags: php, random, shtml

I need to attach a random number to a query string in an SHTML page. It's straightforward to generate the value in PHP:

```
function get_random_id(){
  srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
  return rand(0,1844);
}
```

But how do you use this when the SHTML page uses syntax like this?

```
<img src="<!--#echo var="imagemapgif" -->" name="Image1" width="169" height="41" usemap="#Map" id="Image1">
```

Anyone know of a syntax manual for SHTML pages? Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the answer: Those weird included code are Apache SSI. So concatenating the full time (year, day, hour, minute, second) should create a random value for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [run an external program](http://bignosebird.com/sdocs/execs.shtml) to get a random number using a [server side include](http://bignosebird.com/ssi.shtml).

Comment: I've got a solution documented here: http://devharbor.blogspot.com/2011/04/create-quasi-random-number-with-apache.html It's not a true random number, but it works for what I need.